# Computing Picard groups of quadric hyperplane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know the Picard group of a smooth two dimensional quadric surface is $\mathbb Z^2$, but I am wondering if the computation can be generalized to higher dimension? In particular, is the Picard group of a $n$-dimensional smooth quadric hyperplane $\{\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}x_i^2=0\}\subset\mathbb P^{n+1}$ known?

Comment: Yes - from smoothness, this is equivalent to the class group, and that's Hartshorne exercise II.6.5. The answer is $\Bbb Z$ except when $n=2$, in which case it's $\Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: Not quadric hyperplane!

Comment: Why did you delete your today's question? It is disrespectful to those you have already answered or commented.